# Cant get a razor page many to many navigation to return data from the right hand table for a kendo grid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, kendo-grid

Not sure if I said that right, but I have a razor pages business app in net core 3.1, with quite a few many to many joins. I'm just working on one join at the moment and trying to feed results to a kendo grid via a repository call
Here are the models for the example, which is "Notes" and "NoteTypes" joined by "NoteNoteTypeJoins"

```
public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Short Title")]
    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Note Content")]
    public String NoteText { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

        //some fields left out for brevity

    public ICollection<NoteStaffJoin> NoteStaffJoins { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NoteClientJoin> NoteClientJoins { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NoteOrgJoin> NoteOrgJoins { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NoteNoteTypeJoin> NoteNoteTypeJoins { get; set; }

}
public class NoteNoteTypeJoin
{
    public int NoteNoteTypeJoinID { get; set; }
    public int NoteID { get; set; }
    public int NoteTypeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Saved { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    public Note Note { get; set; }
    public NoteType NoteType { get; set; }


}

public class NoteType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public int? NoteTypeGroupID { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<NoteNoteTypeJoin> NoteNoteTypeJoins { get; set; }

}
public FliveRetryContext(DbContextOptions<FliveRetryContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
    public DbSet<FliveRetry.Models.Note> Note { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FliveRetry.Models.NoteType> NoteType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FliveRetry.Models.NoteNoteTypeJoin> NoteNoteTypeJoin { get; set; }
}
```

The foreign keys etc are all correctly defined as far as I can see by ef core

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NoteNoteTypeJoin] (
    [NoteNoteTypeJoinID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NoteID]             INT           NOT NULL,
    [NoteTypeID]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [Saved]              DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
    [UserID]             INT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_NoteNoteTypeJoin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NoteNoteTypeJoinID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_NoteNoteTypeJoin_Note_NoteID] FOREIGN KEY ([NoteID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Note] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_NoteNoteTypeJoin_NoteType_NoteTypeID] FOREIGN KEY ([NoteTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[NoteType] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NoteNoteTypeJoin_NoteID]
    ON [dbo].[NoteNoteTypeJoin]([NoteID] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NoteNoteTypeJoin_NoteTypeID]
    ON [dbo].[NoteNoteTypeJoin]([NoteTypeID] ASC);
```

I've tried every example on the web for the last week but can't get it right. I eventually got this to work using the ID in the join table, which doesn't need to call the NoteTypes table:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeIDAsync(int notetypeid)
        {
            var noteData = await context.Note
                       .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                       .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                       .Where(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(x => x.NoteTypeID == notetypeid))
                       .ToListAsync();

            return noteData;
        }
```

I had to add this referenceloophandling option to startup.cs to get includes to work at all, thanks Telerik for that info:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson
                    (options => {
                        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    });
```

This also works, again, only querying the left hand table, even though including others:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForUserAsync(int userId)
        {
            var noteData = await context.Note
                      .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                      .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                      .Where(i => i.UserID == userId)
                      .ToListAsync();

            return noteData;
        }
```

I'd like to search by NoteType text rather than by ID, as the id can be different on different releases.
This is what I have at the moment, but it crashes the page, like many other variations:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeAsync(string notetype)
        {            
            var noteData = await context.Note
                       .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                       .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                       .Where(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(x => x.NoteType.Type.ToString() == notetype))
                       .ToListAsync();
            return noteData;
        }
```

This crashes with the following message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<NoteNoteTypeJoin>
.Where(n0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
EntityType: Note
ValueBufferExpression: 
(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
IsNullable: False
), "ID") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
EntityType: Note
ValueBufferExpression: 
(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
IsNullable: False
), "ID") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(n0, "NoteID"))
.Join(
outer: DbSet<NoteType>, 
inner: n0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(n0, "NoteTypeID"), 
outerKeySelector: n1 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(n1, "ID"), 
innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<NoteNoteTypeJoin, NoteType>(
Outer = o, 
Inner = i
))
.Any(n0 => n0.Inner.Type.ToString() == __notetype_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I also don't have intellisense access to the last join, which is stopping me using a lot of suggestions on forums so something like .Where(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Type == notetype)) isn't available because .Type isn't available after NoteNoteTypeJoins.

These are the four many to many relationships I need to filter by:

```
Note = await _context.Note
.Include(i => i.NoteOrgJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Org)
.Include(i => i.NoteClientJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Client)
.Include(i => i.NoteStaffJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Staff)
.Include(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.NoteType)
```

If anyone can suggest a working navigation call rather than joins, that can get me out of trouble for at least the note types call, I will be stoked, If you can show me how to add the other calls in as well, that would be even better. I'm still learning C# and razor so it may be something outside of the call itself but I have tried to stick to the standard setup.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also don't have intellisense access to the last join, which is stopping me using a lot of suggestions on forums so something like .Where(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Type == notetype)) isn't available because .Type isn't available after NoteNoteTypeJoins.

The reason is that implicit client evaluation has been disabled in EF Core 3.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

You could change your code like below:

```
var noteData = await _context.Note
                   .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                   .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)                                    
                   .ToListAsync();

var d = noteData.Where(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(x => x.NoteType.Type.ToString() == notetype))
                .ToList();
```

Another way is that the `Type` property in your `NoteType` class is type of string.No need to use `ToString()` method:

```
var noteData = await _context.Note
                   .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                   .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                   .Where(i => i.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(x => x.NoteType.Type == notetype))
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rena, the first change you suggested works perfectly. The bottom one still returns nothing but I will use the first. I have another level of include to get Notes by Note Type Group, where the structure is like this:     var noteData = await context.Note
                    .Include(n => n.NoteNoteTypeJoins)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.NoteType)
                            .ThenInclude(gt => gt.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins)
                                .ThenInclude(g => g.NoteTypeGroup). I'm trying to tie it together using your methods with no luck

Comment: Would it help if I created a new question and tagged you in it? does that work?

Comment: Also wondering, does this bring all Notes into memory? There could potentially be millions of notes in this case?

Comment: Yes.It would bring all notes into memory.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Rena, learnt a lot from that. Really appreciate you're effort to understand this. This below ended up working from another question I asked about an extra layer, I think it just returns the records I need not the whole lot? :             `var noteData = await context.Note.Where(n =>
                n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(ntj =>
                    ntj.NoteType.Type == notetype))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Archived).OrderByDescending(x => x.NoteDate)
                .ToListAsync();
            return noteData;`

Comment: This also worked to go another level deeper, to notetypegroups: `public async Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotesForNoteTypeGroupAsync(string notetypegroup)
        {            
            var noteData = await context.Note.Where(n =>
                n.NoteNoteTypeJoins.Any(ntj =>
                    ntj.NoteType.NoteTypeNoteTypeGroupJoins.Any(ntg => ntg.NoteTypeGroup.Group == notetypegroup)))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Archived).OrderByDescending(x => x.NoteDate)
                .ToListAsync();            
            return noteData;
        }`